# Cannot see any JavaScript files in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

As I concern security and privacy, also actually I'm facing Chrome(actually chromium Brave)'s high CPU problem, I needed to check source code of suspicious extensions I have.

So first I tried to inspect an extension called Visited (bfcodeehkjogenemacopdbhabjebnbah), it's very simple extension so I thought it shouldn't be hard to inspect. (but of course it should contains at least some JS files, background.js)

But when I opened `Default\Extensions\bfcodeehkjogenemacopdbhabjebnbah` on my editor, there is no JS files, but only five files:

- _metadata\verified_contents.json
- _metadata\computed_hashes.json
- custom.css
- icon128.png
- manifest.json

It's so strange.

I also read [gist](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/78d6c1406c901be02c2d) to inspect Chrome extension source code, I tried all the curl `clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx` way, robwu.nl/crxviewer way, Chrome extension source viewer way. But none of them worked or showed me the with-no-JS-files source tree.

Where the hell is background.js and JS files? How can I see these files??

Comment: Extension doesn't have to contain JS files. It simply adds a [CSS content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) via its manifest.json.

Comment: aha! I think that's it. The extension seems implemented only with the one css file four lines of code.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was because that the extension is implemented only with the one CSS file, and without having power of any JavaScript.

Also I tried debugging the source code with editor and confirmed it works as expected.